# Regex to get line content

Tags: c#, regex

I want to get a line content between "From:" until "\r\n", I heve tried this:

```
    string texto = @"From: .... blabla bla
    Message: blablabalab

    //linha em branco
    From: .... blabla bla
    Message: blablabalab

    //linha em Branco
    From: .... blabla bla
    Message: blablabalab";

   string[] lines = Regex.Split(texto, "From:\\s+\\rn");
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern you're looking for is `@"From:(.*?)\r\n"`. Also, you'll want to use `Regex.Match` rather than `Regex.Split`:

```
string from = Regex.Match(s, @"From:(.*?)\r\n").Value;
```

You can also use `Regex.Matches` if you want to get all the "from"s:

```
string[] froms = Regex.Matches(s, @"From:(.*?)\r\n")
                      .Cast<Match>()
                      .Select(m => m.Value)
                      .ToArray();
```

Comment: doesnt It allow to use pipe?

Comment: I tried

string texto = @"|0140|XX|
     |0150|TEST|TEST|
     |0150|TEST|TEST|";
string[] pedacos = Regex.Matches(texto, @"|0150|(.*?)\r\n")
                      .Cast<Match>()
                      .Select(m => m.Value)
                      .ToArray();

Comment: @user3739007 The pipe character has special meaning in Regex. If you want to use it to search for the character, you need to escape it. (e.g. `"\|"`)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `"From:(.*)$"`
$ is a default sign for line ending in C# regex engine.

You can read more about Regex in C# [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx)